# Oracle Locator Features

Tags: gps, oracle-dbms, oracle-spatial

I have a road network (in shapefile) which is in a projected system (e.g. EPSG:2100). I also have a number of GPS files in WGS84.

I have already stored the data into Oracle 12c (Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production) using just the Locator (and not Spatial and Graph).

I want to perform the following actions:

Create buffered geometries from the existing road links (i.e. linestring to polygon).

Transform the GPS points from WGS84 to EPSG:2100.

Match the (transformed) GPS points with the buffered road links.

When the data are displayed on a web page (with leaflet.js), I want to be able to define an area and select only the links and GPS signals contained in that area.

Will the Locator suffice for that? Obtaining license for Oracle Enterprise and Spatial and Graph is out of the question.

Trying to clarify things a bit further and make the question simpler, all I am asking is if the Oracle's equivalents of PostGIS' ST_Transform, ST_Buffer and ST_Contains are freely available with the Locator or the (paid) Spatial and Graph is required.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.  Consequently, I am going to edit out the second question which is about ArcSDE licensing.  If you cannot find an answer to that here then you can always ask that as a separate question.

Comment: You can do all that with the Locator license. If you are a beginner you will need to learn a few new things but there are less information and tutorials in the web about working with Oracle than about how to do it with PostGIS but it is your choice. Using GeoServer as a middle-ware may help you with the last task, the web service.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am new to Oracle but I have quite adequate experience with PostGIS, in fact I have done exactly the same task with PostGIS (and Map Server). What I do not know (and I cannot figure out from the documentation) is if the required functions are available with the locator license. For starters I need to use the equivalent of ST_Transform, ST_Buffer and ST_Contains. Are they available or they need Spatial and Graph?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information. The [Tour] stresses the importance of asking one question per Question.  You have several questions here. It would be best to ask them one at a time, in order of importance (go through corrections on your first post before asking the others).  You should always specify the exact version of software in use  (12c is a generation of software familes, use something like *12.1.0.2.3*)

Comment: Dear Vince, I edited the question in order to include the exact software version. As per your second remark, I only asked one question: Are the required procedures/functions freely available or not? I am not asking HOW to do each one of the tasks, but whether I am allowed to or not. The "how" is another question indeed, but I think I already have the experience to answer it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions you indicate are all part of Oracle Locator, just under different names:
ST_transform = sdo_cs.transform()
ST_buffer = sdo_geom.sdo_buffer()

But for matching points and lines you do not need to generate buffers. Just use the sdo_within_distance() predicate. Use parallelism to optimize elapsed time. You also don’t need to transform coordinates for that.

Or use the sdo_join() technique.